# RewriteCond и %{HTTP_HOST}

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, .htaccess, apache

Здрaвствуйте. Почему `RewriteCond` не видит переменную `%{HTTP_HOST}`? Или так и должно быть?

Правило НЕ работает:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Правило работает:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example.com
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Для Вашего случая воспользуейтесь выражениями. Замените вашу первую первую строку на:

```
RewriteCond expr "%{HTTP_REFERER} -strmatch '*://%{HTTP_HOST}/*'"
```

Все возможности можно узнать [здесь](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html)